# How to startActivity within RecyclerView CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to add `startActivity()` to my `onClick` listeners in my CustomAdapter class.

`CustomAdapter.java`:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> data;
    public CustomAdapter (List<String> data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rowItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(rowItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(this.data.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           startActivity(new Intent(CustomAdapter.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the following error in my IDE:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.kenadams.app.CustomAdapter, java.lang.Class<com.kenadams.app.LoginActivity>)'
```

Initially , I thought this was happening because my `CustomAdapter` class was `static`. So, I made it non-static. But, the problem still persists. Pls guide me on making this intent work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you customer adapter class you need to get context using constructor.

```
private Context mcon;
```

and in constructor->

```
public CustomAdapter (Context _mcon, List<String> data){

this.mcon = _mcon;
    this.data = data;
}
```

and then in onClickListener->

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    mcon.startActivity(new Intent(mcon, LoginActivity.class));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CustomAdapter.this` in
`startActivity(new Intent(CustomAdapter.this, LoginActivity.class));`

Use the Activity context of which you are using the adapter.

But the correct way of starting another activity should be from the activity. Perhaps you could call the method of your activity within the ViewHolder. Which will start your desired activity